# Need help to build a time based notification of microsoft Bot

Tags: node.js, notifications, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I am looking for a solution where I need my bot to send notifications to all the users that have interacted with the bot before. This should happen on time demand, for example I would like to send notification only for alternate Friday at 5pm CDT.

I have trie the sample [16.proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) but the the notification trigger is based on a controller so we have to send explicit request to 
http://localhost:3978/api/notify to proactively message users from the bot.

I am using bot builder Nodejs sdk 4.x to build the bot.

I would like notifications to go on demand based on the set time and date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to meet your requirement is following the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) that you tried. To send a notification to uses, you should send a request to `api/notify` endpoint.

You can [create a scheduled webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) to send this request to your bot so that your bot will send notifications to your users.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Stanley Gong, I have 2 more followup questions. 
1) Sample says "This project has a notify endpoint that will trigger the proactive messages to be sent to all users who have previously messaged the bot"

Is there any idea we can send to users who have NOT previously messaged the bot ? I agree we won't have there address / user Id info. do so but just wondering if there is any trick.

2) We are using Msteams channel so will this sample be OK to go with for Ms teams bot ?

Comment: Hi @RoyJ , For Q1 : the bot proactive/notification demo is based on Conversation ID to send activity/messages to users. Once users  messages a bot or attend a chat , users will get a Conversation ID .All messages transform between bot and users all are based on Conversation ID. So there is no way to send messages to a user who has no messaged with bot previously as user has no Concersation ID .
For Q2 : Yes , Ms teams channel is ok to go with it.